# Selenium's Send_Keys not capturing pyqt5's QLabel Text

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, user-interface, pyqt5

I know this is going to be a simple fix but I can't figure out why I cant get Send_Keys to type pyqt5's QLabel's text

this is what I have so far:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QLabel, QLineEdit, QGridLayout, QGroupBox, QDialog
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from requests import get
import time

class Window(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.setWindowTitle("Project PiBu!!")

        self.game_name = QLabel("Game Name:", self)
        self.game_line_edit = QLineEdit(self)
        self.search_button = QPushButton("Search", self)
        self.search_button.clicked.connect(self.on_click)
        self.game = QLabel(self)
        self.results = QLabel("Results For:", self)
        self.meta_critic_label = QLabel("Metacritic Score:", self)
        self.user_score_label = QLabel("User Score:", self)
        self.meta_critic_score = ""
        self.user_score_score = ""

        self.createGridLayout()
        self.windowLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.windowLayout.addWidget(self.horizontalGroupBox)
        self.setLayout(self.windowLayout)

        self.show()

    def createGridLayout(self):
        self.horizontalGroupBox = QGroupBox()
        self.layout = QGridLayout()
        self.layout.setColumnStretch(1, 3)
        self.layout.setColumnStretch(2, 3)
        self.layout.setColumnStretch(3, 3)
        self.layout.setColumnStretch(4, 3)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.game_name, 0, 0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.game_line_edit, 0, 1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.search_button, 0, 2)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.results, 1, 0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.game, 2, 0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.meta_critic_label, 1, 1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.user_score_label, 1, 2)

        self.horizontalGroupBox.setLayout(self.layout)


    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_click(self):
        self.game.setText(self.game_line_edit.text())

        # options = Options()
        # options.add_argument("--headless")  # Runs Chrome in headless mode.
        # options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')  # # Bypass OS security model
        # options.add_argument('start-maximized')
        # options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
        # options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
        # driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path='/home/littlejiver/Downloads/chromedriver')

        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.driver.get("https://www.metacritic.com/game")

        print("Headless Chrome Initialized on Linux OS")

        self.search_element = self.driver.find_element_by_name("search_term")
        self.search_element.clear()
        self.search_element.send_keys(self.game)

        # self.game_line_edit.setText("")

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Im getting this error:

```
TypeError: object of type 'QLabel' has no len()
```

I cant figure out how to capture the text entered into the "QLineEdit" that is captured in the "QLabel" into a variable that can be "read" by send_keys

Hopefully this make sense :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

it was as simple as changeing

```
 self.search_element.send_keys(self.game)
```

to:

```
self.search_element.send_keys(self.game.text())
```

Comment: does anyone know how to speed the process up?